# Should unused tables be archived?

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

There is a table in our database that takes about 25GB. It is no longer used by the current code.

Will it give any performance improvements (for rest of the tables) if we archive this table, even though it's not queried/used? Please provide explanation.

We are using MySQL with AWS Aurora.

Comment: You mean with archive storing the data or converting it in a [ARCHIVE Storage Engine](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/archive-storage-engine.html) ?

Comment: @RaymondNijland well that would also be a question, whether to [archive it in AWS Glacier](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/archiving-data-from-relational-databases-to-amazon-glacier-via-aws-dms/) or what you mentioned.. I haven't done archiving of tables before

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Archiving tables will not have any impact on Aurora. Unused pages are evicted from buffer pool eventually [1], and since then, they never get pulled back onto the db instances, unless you make a query that would touch those pages.

You would continue to pay storage costs (and other in-direct costs like snapshots) by keeping them as unused. A better option would be to move the unused data to a new cluster, create a snapshot out of it, and remove the cluster. You can always recover the data when you need it by restoring a snapshot. The original database can then be cleaned by dropping these unused tables. This way you end up only paying for the snapshot, which is cheaper.

You could also export the data out of mysql (CSV let say) and store it in S3/Glacier. Only caviat is that when you need to access the data, it can end up being a much more time consuming effort to load it back to an existing or new database cluster.

[1] Buffer pool uses LRU for eviction. When you workload runs for long, you would eventually end up evicting all the pages associated with the unused table. Link: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html

Comment: Thank you, would you have a reference to corroborate "*Unused tables are evicted from buffer pool eventually*"?

Comment: Buffer pool uses LRU for eviction. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-buffer-pool.html (I updated the answer to state "Unused pages are evicted" instead of "Unused tables are evicted")

Answer (score 0):

Yes, archiving will improve performance also along with reduction in side and quickness of of backup/recovery cycles.
I have tried it on different projects in my recent full time job and results are amazing. For those who deny I would only say:

- Reduction in footprint reduce disk IO and scans
- Reduction in foot print reduce buffer requirements and hence RAM requirements.

Answer (score -2):

**YES**, archiving infrequently used data will ease the burden on faster and more frequently accessed data storage systems. Older data that is unlikely to be needed often is put on systems that don’t need to have the speed and accessibility of systems that contain data still in use

Archived data is stored on a lower-cost tier of storage, serving as a way to reduce primary storage consumption and related costs. Typically, data reduplication is performed on data being moved to a lower storage tier, which reduces the overall storage footprint and lowers secondary storage costs

Comment: So basically you are saying moving files which aren't accessed annymore make the server go faster...Only reason for archiving with archive storage engine is to safe diskspace..

Comment: This answer talks about data storage costs, which I am already aware of. My question if about read/write performance, CPU/RAM consumption, etc. of other tables. How/why will archiving the unused table make the other tables more efficient?

Comment: @Kartik, it won't.  Data you are not accessing should have no impact.  One exception is backups made with `mysqldump`, which may temporarily cause pages to move in and out of the buffer pool, causing a transient performance impact... but backups made by RDS snapshots don't do this.